# FFMPEG output to multiple rtmp and synchronize them

Tags: ffmpeg

presume I have a video, and I use filter to crop them let say 1/2 and 1/2 width to 2 rtmp output streams.

Now 2 clients will subscribe to these stream let say

vlc1 - stream 1 | vlc2 - stream 2

how can I synchronize them to play at the same time (I always see 1 client play faster or slower than other)

Here is the code

```
ffmpeg -re -stream_loop -1 -i sample.mp4 \
  -filter:v "crop=in_w/2:in_h:0:0" -c:a copy -f flv rtmp://localhost/live/1 \
  -filter:v "crop=in_w/2:in_h:in_w/2:0" -c:a copy -f flv rtmp://localhost/live/2
```

## Gotcha1

Found out the problem was stream_loop and with each iteration and filter it produces some delay.

From now, the only solution works for me is

1. Playing the original file (with loop) and output to a rtmp stream
2. Create 2 stream that read the origin stream, do cropping and then output 2 rtmp streams

```
ffmpeg -i rtmp://localhost/live/feed -filter:v crop=in_w/2:in_h:0:0 -c:a copy -f flv rtmp://localhost/live/1

ffmpeg -i rtmp://localhost/live/feed -filter:v crop=in_w/2:in_h:in_w/2:0 -c:a copy -f flv rtmp://localhost/live/2
```

Answer (score 1):

RTMP does not have synchronization features. You would need to develop an out of band time system that the players sync too (possibly NTP) and add a stream start time the the initial RTMP onMedatata script tag. You then need to modify the VLC source code to read the tag and resolve the timestamps correctly.

Comment: Thank you but thats a lot of works that I can do right now, can you check the edited question and give me suggestion